# PCA factor $\frac{1}{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, principal-component-analysis

I've seen multiple PCA derivations where the $\frac{1}{n}$ (for variance) or $\frac{1}{n-1}$ (for sample variance) is just omitted, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Details). I see that they are proportional to each other but is this just something they did to make the derivation easier or is the scaling factor not necessary in practice?

Comment: This will become clear when you read about [(unbiased) sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance).

Comment: @j For many applications, the scaling factor is unnecessary. In particular, if we are merely interested in obtaining the principal components or if we want the ratio of variances between certain components, then any scaling will "cancel out".

Comment: that makes sense, but if we need the eigenvalues we always need the scaling factor right?

Comment: Yes: if you want the actual eigenvalues (i.e. the variance associated with the given principal components), then you need the scaling factor.